# Switch case checkbox

Tags: php, formulário, checkbox, switch

Preciso que, ao marcar as opções de um `checkbox`, seja informada uma frase diferente, mesmo que eu marque dois ou mais checkbox diferentes. Neste caso a baixo, usei `switch` mas estou com dificuldades para serem dadas as respostas corretas. Como posso fazer isso?

Segue o código:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt-br">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Avatarizador :)</title>
</head>

<body>

    <form action="" method="post">
        <input type="checkbox" name="erea" value="SSA"> Salvador
        <br/>
        <input type="checkbox" name="erea" value="BRI"> Brisas
        <br/>
        <input type="checkbox" name="erea" value="PTS"> Pontes
        <br/>
        <input type="checkbox" name="erea" value="PTV"> Porto Velho
        <br/>
        <input type="submit" value="Avatarizar">
    </form>

    <?PHP

        /*

        $image_path = "salvador.png";
        $image_path = "brisas.png";
        $image_path = "pontes.png";
        $image_path = "portovelho.png";

        $image_path = "salvador_pontes.png";
        $image_path = "brisas_pontes.png";

        $image_path = "salvador_pontes_portovelho.png";
        $image_path = "brisas_pontes_portovelho.png";

        */


    $e = isset($_POST["erea"])?$_POST["erea"]:"XX";
        switch ($e) {

            /* Pontes + Porto Velho */
            case "PTS":
                $r = "Pontes";
                break;
            case "PTV":
                $r = "Porto Velho";
                break;
            case "PTS":
            case "PTV":
                $r = "Pontes + Porto Velho";
                break;

            /* Salvador */                
            case "SSA":
                $r = "Salvador";
                break;
            case "SSA":
            case "PTS":
                $r = "Salvador + Pontes";
                break;
            case "SSA":
            case "PTV":
                $r = "Salvador + Porto Velho";
                break;
            case "SSA":
            case "PTS":
            case "PTV":
                $r = "Salvador + Pontes + Porto Velho";
                break;

            /* Brisas */       
            case "BRI":
                $r = "Brisas";
                break;
            case "BRI":
            case "PTS":
                $r = "Brisas + Pontes";
                break;
            case "BRI":
            case "PTV":
                $r = "Brisas + Porto Velho";
                break;
            case "BRI":
            case "PTS":
            case "PTV":
                $r = "Brisas + Pontes + Porto Velho";
                break;
            default:
               $r = ""; /* Avatar Puro */
       }
       echo "Voce escolheu por o selo de $r";
    ?>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Para gerar sua frase com base nos valores selecionados, você pode fazer dessa forma.

```
 $('input[type=button]').bind('click',function(){

    var resultado = '';
        $('input[type=checkbox]:checked').each(function() {
        if(resultado!=''){resultado += "+";}
        resultado += $(this).val();
    });    

    alert(resultado);

  });
```

Veja se ajuda você.

Exemplo funcionando [aqui](https://jsfiddle.net/eeuzj8ra/2/).

Comment: Mas preciso que ele mostre as frases que estão dentro do case, não o que está escrito nos valores. Depois eu ainda vou ter que substituir cada frase por um $image_path = "nome.png"; nos case, onde um código vai selecionar as fotos corretas para se transformarem em marca d'água.

Pode ver o site que estou modificando aqui: http://ilhas.16mb.com/

Comment: Se você vai suibstituir cada frase pq nao faz isso com os valores do checkbox em vez das frases, ou vc tem algum "Porto Velho.jpg" com espaco em branco e tudo mais?
Como vc vai fazer com as N variacoes que vc pode ter nessa concatenacao de valores seleiconados.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/eeuzj8ra/2/  veja um novo exemplo aqui, pégando os textos que vc quer.

Comment: Estou tentando recriar isso: http://pastebin.com/FJ4s2pC4

Comment: Aqui na empresa pastebin é bloqueado, vc nao consegue jogar no fiddler? ai posso ajudalo

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/nrcdwpy4/2/

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/33587/discussion-between-andre-and-rboschini).